# Pandas resample data to the second, grouping by every ~10 seconds

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

Say I have the following data frame:

```
>>> df
                       a
2019-04-05 00:00:00  2.0                
2019-04-05 00:00:01  1.0
2019-04-05 00:00:02  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:03  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:04  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:05  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:06  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:07  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:08  3.0
2019-04-05 00:00:09  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:10  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:11  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:12  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:13  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:14  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:15  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:16  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:17  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:18  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:19  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:20  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:21  5.0
2019-04-05 00:00:22  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:23  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:24  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:25  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:26  6.0
2019-04-05 00:00:27  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:28  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:29  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:30  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:31  NaN
```

I would like to have 1 value per every 7 seconds (assuming there is a value, otherwise just a NaN), so a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
>>> df
                       a
2019-04-05 00:00:00  2.0                
2019-04-05 00:00:01  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:02  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:03  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:04  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:05  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:06  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:07  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:08  3.0
2019-04-05 00:00:09  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:10  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:11  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:12  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:13  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:14  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:15  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:16  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:17  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:18  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:19  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:20  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:21  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:22  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:23  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:24  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:25  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:26  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:27  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:28  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:29  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:30  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:31  NaN
```

The 7 second point is arbitrary, I would actually be taking values roughly every minute. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
df = df.resample('7s').first()
```

but that produces the following dataframe instead:

```
                       a
2019-04-05 00:00:00  2.0
2019-04-05 00:00:07  3.0
2019-04-05 00:00:14  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:21  5.0
2019-04-05 00:00:28  4.0
```

Note: I am not bothered by the lack of `NaN`'s between these points, as they are implied. I am just not happy with the timing, as it is forcing a value every 7 seconds, where as I just want to disallow values to be within 7 seconds of each other, not necessitate a value every 7 seconds.

Edith for clarity:

DATAFRAME I DON'T WANT:

```
                       a
2019-04-05 00:00:00  2.0
2019-04-05 00:00:07  3.0
2019-04-05 00:00:14  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:21  5.0
2019-04-05 00:00:28  4.0
```

DATAFRAME I DO WANT:

```
>>> df
                       a
2019-04-05 00:00:00  2.0                
2019-04-05 00:00:01  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:02  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:03  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:04  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:05  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:06  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:07  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:08  3.0
2019-04-05 00:00:09  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:10  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:11  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:12  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:13  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:14  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:15  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:16  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:17  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:18  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:19  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:20  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:21  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:22  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:23  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:24  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:25  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:26  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:27  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:28  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:29  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:30  NaN
2019-04-05 00:00:31  NaN
```

OR:

```
>>> df
                       a
2019-04-05 00:00:00  2.0
2019-04-05 00:00:08  3.0
2019-04-05 00:00:20  4.0
2019-04-05 00:00:28  4.0
```

Comment: Resample the result back to original frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't strictly using pandas methods, but it gets the job done.

```
c = 8
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c += 1
    if c > 7 and not(np.isnan(row[0])):
        c=0
    else:
        row[0] = np.nan
```

once applied to `df` will return the desired dataframe.

Edit:

For a dataframe of `n` columns, and a value every `x` rows:

```
c = [x+1 for i in range(df.shape[1])]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c = [i+1 for i in c]
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if c[i] > x and not(np.isnan(row[i])):
            c[i] = 0
        else:
            row[i] = np.nan
```

Second edit:

The above assumes there is a `NaN` at each time value. The below works with gaps in the dataframe:

```
c = [dt.datetime(1,1,1) for i in range(df.shape[1])]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if index.to_pydatetime() - c[i] > dt.timedelta(seconds=x) and not(np.isnan(row[i])):
            c[i] = index.to_pydatetime()
        else:
            row[i] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

You can upsample your dataframe, you were very close;

```
df = df.resample('7s').first()
df = df.resample(rule='1s')
```

This will create a dataframe with NaN's for the newly inserted rows on the seconds it added.

Comment: This doesn't produce a dataframe for me, it just turns `df` into a `DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<Second>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]`

Comment: Can someone explain this code? I dont understand these rows.

Answer (score 0):

What about filling the NA values before resampling?

```
df = df.fillna('something').resample('7s').first()
```

Then the values will not be forced:

```
                    a
2019-04-05 00:00:00 2
2019-04-05 00:00:07 something
2019-04-05 00:00:14 something
2019-04-05 00:00:21 5
2019-04-05 00:00:28 4
```

Note that if you fill the NA with a string like `something`, it will convert the entire column into `object` instead of `float`. So if you want to maintain the datatype, you could use `df.fillna(0)` instead

Comment: that still forces values to be aligned on every 7 second mark, I just want there to be no 2 values within 7 seconds of each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df.resample("7s").apply(lambda s: s.first_valid_index()).a]
```

If you want intermediate values to be filled with NaN then

```
df1 = df.loc[df.resample("7s").apply(lambda s: s.first_valid_index()).a]
df1.resample("1s").apply(lambda s: None if s.empty else s)
```

Edit:

Based on clarification, here we go:

```
df[df.rolling(window="7s", closed='neither').sum().isna()]
```

Fill it NaN using the upsampling code shown above.

**Edit-2**

We have to use loop over rows, as decision to emit a value depends of previously emitted values:

```
def f():
    skip = 0
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if skip == 0:
            if pd.notna(row.a):
                yield row
                skip = 7
        else:
            skip = skip - 1

pd.DataFrame(f())
```

Comment: This produces the dataframe I said I *didn't* want edit: dataframe**

Comment: What do you mean by `database`?

Comment: I meant dataframe, sorry

Comment: Edited the answer. Check. The only diff with your expected output is in 00:00:20. Why is 00:00:20 NaN in your expected output?

Comment: do you mean 00:00:21? 00:00:20 is 4.0

Comment: Yes. I meant 00:00:21.

Comment: This is because I only want a value every 7 seconds. So at `00:00:19` the most recent value seen is `3.0` at `00:00:08`, so when it reaches `00:00:20` the nearest value is over 7 seconds away (only looking backward). At `00:00:21` the nearest value is only 1 away, so `5.0` is set to `NaN`

Comment: Got it. Earlier I thought you want to keep first value in every 7s group. Check the new solution.

Comment: I just tried that, and it seemed to work for all values except for the 4.0 at `00:00:28`